# Split string after last underscore in R

Tags: r, regex, string, split

I have a string like "ABC_Something_Filename". How can I split it into "ABC_Something" and "Filename" in R?

I do not want to remove anything. I want both components - before and after last underscore.

Edit: I tried using what's mentioned for columns separation but that is too extensive for my use case. Hence, I finding a regex alternative to simply split a string

Comment: Use group capture? Could you show what has failed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option would be to use `strsplit` with a negative lookahead which asserts that the underscore on which to split is the final one in the input:

```
input <- "ABC_Something_Filename"
parts <- strsplit(input, "_(?!.*_)", perl=TRUE)[[1]]
parts

[1] "ABC_Something" "Filename"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_match` and capture data in two groups.

```
x <- 'ABC_Something_Filename'
stringr::str_match(x, '(.*)_(.*)')[, -1]
#[1] "ABC_Something" "Filename"
```